# does Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") use activex?

Tags: asp-classic

im planning on using asp classic to create an XML file for users to download, however i am not able to do this via activex. upon checking around, i noticed that one of the more common statements is
`Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")`

does it use activex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately "ActiveX" is just some marketing spin for COM components. (Putting X on the end of words back then is the same as putting i at the start of words today)

However over time ActiveX has become associated more with control components, COM components that have some UI, which clearly you can't use server-side.

The place to start is with

```
 Dim xml: Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
```

This is a COM object so strictly speaking it is an ActiveX component however as with other components like ADODB it works fine in server side code like ASP